# How to display WFS layer on web

Tags: javascript, wfs, html, web

I am working on a project where displaying data from a [WFS](https://wfs.geonorge.no/skwms1/wfs.tilgjengelighettettsted?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities) from [this site](https://kartkatalog.geonorge.no/metadata/uuid/3bec7256-86c2-4d43-a122-0760a6a21790), but I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how. I would like to know if this is possible, or if I am wasting my time. Through my research i have come across terms like geoserver og openlayers, and I have grown conserned that i can only access the WFS if it is within one of these (making my WFS useless).

Can anyone clerifye this for me? And if it is possible, can someone show me a simple example?

**UPDATE:**

The Idea is to make a web page where users can view the data. Since the data is updated daily or weekly it would be nice to connect to the WFS client. My problem, is I don't understand how to make a proper GetFeature URL, and how to handel it when i do. 
I just recently discoverd that uploading the data throu a webpage might be a posible solution, and therfore havent had much time to learn how it works. I do however see that this solution might be much better and much more accessible that a qgis plugin, which is what i am making now, and might therfore be worth the time. I have allready spent a week on this, and will spend more time if it is possible. But I don't wan't to spend any more time if it is a dead end.

Comment: Please explain in more details what is the problem. That service seems to run on a not completely standard WFS server and the schemata are rather complecated (for example http://skjema.test.geonorge.no/SOSI/produktspesifikasjon/TilgjengelighetTettsted/4.5/TilgjengelighetTettsted.xsd) but service does send data https://wfs.geonorge.no/skwms1/wfs.tilgjengelighettettsted?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&TypeName=app:TettstedVei&outputformat=text/xml;%20subtype=gml/3.2.1&maxfeatures=1

Comment: The WFS 1.1.0 service doesn't seem to be working correctly (I just get errors on DescribeFeatureType).  I have a feeling that OpenLayers can't handle WFS 2.0, so you might be stuck.

Comment: DescribeFeatureType just requires outputformat, which may be against the standard https://wfs.geonorge.no/skwms1/wfs.tilgjengelighettettsted?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=DescribeFeatureType&TypeName=app:TettstedVei&outputformat=text/xml;%20subtype=gml/3.2.1. The result has a link that I included in my first comment.

Answer (score 2):

To display WFS data on your website, you need a) the data and b) to show it.

The data resides on a map server, GeoServer being one of them. On your website, you use a library such as OpenLayers or Leaflet to fetch the data from the server and display it.

In your case, you want to display the data from an existing server, so you would only need OpenLayers (or another library) to show it. You can see it in this [demo](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html).

Note that you would need to read the `GetCapabilities` request from the data server in order to build the proper `GetFeature` URL. This `GetCapabilities` URL is the one provided in the website describing the data in your post.

Comment: I am pretty sure that OpenLayers cannot visualize out-of-the-box  the  complex GML data from that WFS service and it may be hard to find any other ready made javascript solutions. What might work is to download data with GetFeature request to local disk and continue with QGIS and this extension https://github.com/BRGM/gml_application_schema_toolbox

Comment: @JGH Thank you for your clerification. I am trying to duplicate the demo with my WFS, but I am having trouble with the url. I think the problem lies in outputFormat=application/json, as my WFS dosen't to have that outputFormat, but I am not entierly sure

Comment: @user30184 I see, then that might be my problem. Thank you for the suggestion, but the database the WFS is connected to might opdate daily. I therfor wanted the page to load the layer with all object whenever the page was opend.