# WFS 2.0 in QGIS 3

Tags: wfs, qgis-3

I have a WFS server I am desperately trying to get data from. It is possible in WFS 2.0 Client in QGIS 2, but now that QGIS 3 is out (and seemingly with a WFS 2 option) I wanted to try this instead. It does however not work, and I am left with this error message:

```
Layer is not valid: The layer restrictToRequestBBOX='1' srsname='EPSG:4258' typename='app:TettstedInngangBygg' url='https://wfs.geonorge.no/skwms1/wfs.tilgjengelighettettsted' version='2.0.0' table="" sql= is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map. Reason:
```

Does anyone know why this error message appears? I am using [this](https://wfs.geonorge.no/skwms1/wfs.tilgjengelighettettsted?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities) WFS from [this site](https://kartkatalog.geonorge.no/metadata/kartverket/tilgjengelighet-tettsted-wfs/3bec7256-86c2-4d43-a122-0760a6a21790)

Comment: Did you try to download the GML from the WFS service on disk and use the GML application schema extension as I suggested in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/275042/how-to-display-wfs-layer-on-web?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am affraid I am not entirly sure how to do that. I can load the file from WFS 2.0 client, and then save it as GML, but when I try to open it with that extension i get an UnicodeEncodeError

Comment: If the service is public could you add a GetFeature request for getting some test data?

Comment: It is public, this request url gives me some data in xml. If I wan't to do it in QGIS, I have to go though WFS 2.0 Client

https://wfs.geonorge.no/skwms1/wfs.tilgjengelighettettsted?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=app%3ATettstedInngangBygg&count=2